# "getElementById not a function" when trying to parse an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, getelementbyid, gm-xmlhttprequest

I'm running `GM_xmlhttpRequest` (in a Greasemonkey script) and storing the `responseText` into a newly created HTML element:

```
var responseHTML = document.createElement('HTML');
...
onload: function() { responseHTML.innerHTML = response.responseText; }
```

And then I am trying to find an element in `responseHTML`:

```
console.log(responseHTML.getElementsByTagName('div'));
console.log(responseHTML.getElementById('result_0'));
```

The first works fine, but not the second. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementById` is not a method of HTML elements. It is a method of the document node. As such you can't do:

```
div.getElementById('foo'); // invalid code
```

You can implement your own function to search the DOM by recursively going through `children`. On newer browsers you can even use the `querySelector` method. For minimal development you can use libraries like jQuery or sizzle.js (the query engine behind jQuery).

Answer (score 8):

Use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) to convert `responseText` into a searchable DOM tree.
Also, your attempts to search/use anything derived from `responseText`, must occur inside the `onload` function.

Use code like this:

```js
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    ...
    onload:     parseAJAX_ResponseHTML,
    ...
} );

function parseAJAX_ResponseHTML (respObject) {
    var parser      = new DOMParser ();
    var responseDoc = parser.parseFromString (respObject.responseText, "text/html");

    console.log (responseDoc.getElementsByTagName('div'));
    console.log (responseDoc.getElementById('result_0'));
}
```

Of course, also verify that a node with id `result_0` is actually in the returned HTML.  (Using Firebug, Wireshark, etc.)

Comment: His code works the same as yours: meaning your code doesn't work for the same reason - getElementById is not a method of HTML element, it is a method of document.

Comment: @slebetman: No, my code does work and responseDoc **is** a document. ... You can see that it works at http://fiddle.jshell.net/UEuKZ/show/. (The code is **Firefox only**, which is okay since this is a `Greasemonkey` question).

Comment: Ah, missed the greasemonkey tag. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I tend to eschew the DOMParser 'cause I've had trouble getting it work in the past ^_^

But anyways, I see why it wasn't working now.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to store the response in an element neither use DOMParser()

Just set the responseType to 'document' and the response will be parsed automatically and stored in the responseXML

Example:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('get','http://www.taringa.net');
ajax.responseType = 'document';
ajax.onload = function(){
    console.log(ajax.responseXML); //And this is a document which may execute getElementById
};
ajax.send();
```