# GM Cross domain Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

Trying to prepopulate a form on a client's website with data from our database using a greasemonkey script, but i can't figure out how to get around the same origin policy..

I am using GM_xmlhttpRequest nd even specified @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest but no luck..

Here's my script what am I doing wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ORL Prepop Test
// @namespace   customertrackinc.com
// @description Prepopulate ORL Fields
// @include     https://www.openroadlending.com/Apply.aspx*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.style.background = "white";
document.getElementById('ctl00_TopMenu_T872C6B14002_Menu1').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('Header').style.background = "#968888";
document.getElementById('Header').style.color = "black";
document.getElementById('Header').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
document.getElementById('Header').style.backgroundPosition="bottom left"; 
document.getElementById('Header').style.border = "1px solid black";
document.getElementById('Header').style.padding = "1em";
document.getElementById('SuperLinks').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('SideBar').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('Logo').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('TagLine').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('LP_DIV_1368197056862').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('Header').innerHTML =  '<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; padding:.5em;">Script is working so far...</div>';


var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('sfContentBlock'),
i = boxes.length;
while(i--) {
    boxes[i].style.display = "none;";
}

var all=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].style.display = "none";
}

var all=document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].style.display = "none";
}

function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
 if (elem.addEventListener)
     elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 else if (elem.attachEvent)
     elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}

function startAjax(){
    var param1ct = document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtFirstName1').value;
    var param2ct = document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtLastName1').value;
    var param3ct = document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtStreetAddress1').value;
    var urlct = "URL INTENTIONALLY OMITTED/ajaxhandler.php?fname="+param1ct+"&lname="+param2ct+"&addr="+param3ct;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: urlct,
        onload: function(response) {
            var statusct = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('status')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var fnamect = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('fname')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var addrct = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('addr')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var lnamect = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('lname')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var cityct = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var statect = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('street')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var zipct = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('zip')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var emailct = xmlhttpp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('email')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

            document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML=statusct;
            if(status == "Bingo"){
                var confirmMsg = "*User Found*\n\nName: "+fnamect+" "+lnamect+"\nAddress: "+addrct+"\nCity: "+cityct+"\nState: "+statect+"\nZip: "+zipct+"\nEmail: "+emailct+"\n\nClick 'OK' To populate fields or click 'Cancel' if this is not the correct info.";
                var fillOrNot = confirm(confirmMsg);
                if(fillOrNot === true){                     
                    document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtFirstName1').value = fnamect;
                    document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtLastName1').value = lnamect;
                    document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtStreetAddress1').value = addrct;
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("Header").innerHTML="Aborted";
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

var first_name_field = document.getElementById('BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtFirstName1');
addEventHandler(first_name_field,"keyup",startAjax);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `xmlhttpp` but it's not defined anywhere.  You need to parse on `response`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467331/331508).