# Parse HTML page and access table information in javascript outside of the browser

Tags: javascript

I want to access a web page through javascript using 'XMLHttpRequest', grab the output and retrieve the table information from the output using 'getElementbyID' or 'getElementsbyName' methods. I could get to the output but the following code but retrieval of the table info gives an error.

```
var webPage = 'xx';
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var reqWebPage = new XMLHttpRequest();
reqWebPage.open('GET', webPage, false);
reqWebPage.send();
var responseHTTP = reqWebPage.responseText;
var tableMain = responseHTTP.getElementbyID('main-table');
console.log tableMain
```

Error:TypeError: responseHTTP.getElementsbyName is not a function. Is there a way to get around this? I am running this javascript on node and not the browser.

Comment: You can try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466812/getelementbyid-not-a-function-when-trying-to-parse-an-ajax-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466812/getelementbyid-not-a-function-when-trying-to-parse-an-ajax-response) Or isn't that what u want?

Comment: You can also try `var responseHTTP = reqWebPage.responseText; var div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = responseHTTP; var tableMain = div.getElementbyID('main-table');`

Comment: @Will - But doesn't your suggestion assume that a document object will be present.  That is not the case when parsing an AJAX response.

Comment: onno204's suggestion looks like the right way to go.

Comment: @onno204 - That still points to working on a browser. On a browser, I could use document object. I just parsed the output through a dom-parser to get the required info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that responseText have not a `getElementbyID` method, you should get the "main-table" element by iterating on child nodes of `reqWebPage.responseText`

Comment: Parsed the responseText using the dom-parser to get the required table details.                                                                                                     
var DomParser = require('dom-parser');
var parser = new DomParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(responseHTTP);
var element = dom.getElementById('main-table').innerHTML;